# Enable the specified Linux kernel option via CLI resolving deps and avoiding conflicts?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

`make menuconfig` can be used to configure Linux kernel tree interactively. When an option is enabled there, all of its dependencies are automatically resolved (i.e. either marked `y` or `m`), and if enabling an option isn't possible for some reason or in some way, it's cleanly disallowed. However, is there a possibility to enable a given option via CLI non-interactively, automatically resolving dependencies and avoiding conflicts much the same way?

Say, I want to set `CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK=m` option. That option depends on `NET`, `INET` and `NETFILTER` options, which should become enabled as well. I could just change the `.config` file and include `CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK=m` there, but that wouldn't resolve dependencies by itself nor check against any possible arising conflicts. So how could I do this?

Basically, I'd want something like `make setoption CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK=m`, but I can't find anything like that.

Comment: You add your option to the *.config* and run `make olddefconfig`, but be aware that .config might have conflicting options that you have to disable first. Also, you have to provide dependencies if needed, means you have to add all of them to *.config*.